# Mutual ranks from distance matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, rank, euclidean-distance

Struggling to figure out how to convert a distance matrix, with true distances into a matrix with the mutual ranks (ranked closeness of each point to another).

I have a large distance matrix output from pca2euclid - but this is an example:

```
          v1         v2         v3
v1 0.0000000 0.12807130 0.13881717
v2 0.1280713 0.00000000 0.01074588
v3 0.1388172 0.01074588 0.00000000
```

There must be an easy way to convert this to mutual rank matrix.

Comment: mutualrank<-rowRanks(matrix)+rowRanks(t(matrix))/2?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some explanation or code instead of using comments as you did.

Answer (score 0):

First provide a reproducible version of the data with `dput()`.

```
dst <- structure(c(0, 0.1280713, 0.1388172, 0.1280713, 0, 0.01074588, 
0.13881717, 0.01074588, 0), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("v1", "v2", "v3"), c("v1", "v2", "v3")))
```

Now we create a `dist` object from the matrix and use that to create the ranks:

```
dst.d <- as.dist(dst)   # Convert to a dist object
dst.r <- rank(dst.d)    # Compute ranks
dst.rank <- dst         # Copy original matrix
dst.rank[lower.tri(dst.rank)] <- dst.r    # Replace values with ranks
dst.rank[upper.tri(dst.rank)] <- dst.r    # Replace values with ranks
dst.rank
#    v1 v2 v3
# v1  0  2  3
# v2  2  0  1
# v3  3  1  0
```